# TFS - Run SSH task executes file and gives warning in end

Tags: shell, ssh, tfs, azure-devops

I am running a shell file using "Run SSH task" in TFS. The script executes completely. But on moving to the next task, it takes time. It gives this warning in the end which consumes almost 10 min more.

> ### [warning]Failed to delete the script file copied to the remote machine. Error = Error: Not connected.

Comment: Could you share your build definition and entire build log? Is your script running successfully locally?

Comment: Yes it executes perfectly on local machine. This is not the build log - its the Release log. It is connecting to remote machine and executing a series of shell commands.

Comment: Does this issue always occurs? Can you share the release log?